Check if a network is installed in Metamask using its RPC with react js
i am using this method  to add a custom network with a custom rpc  to my metamask :
 async function addMaticNetwork() {
  try {
    // Check if the Matic network RPC URL is already added

    await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
      params: [
        {
          chainId: "0x89",
          rpcUrls: [
            "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/KEY",
          ],
          chainName: "Matic Mainnet",
          nativeCurrency: {
            name: "MATIC",
            symbol: "MATIC",
            decimals: 18,
          },
          blockExplorerUrls: ["https://polygonscan.com/"],
        },
      ],
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

The problem is that function always get called even if the network exists , so it opens Metamask popup to install the network than to switch to it . So i want to check if this network exists or not by its RPC and not the id because i can have another network with the same id .
Thank you

You can use the wallet_switchEthereumChain method. If the network you are attempting to change doesn't exist, this method would fail and then you could add it to the wallet.

Thank you for your answer , the problem that the wallet_switchEthereumChain use the network id to connect , but i have two networks with the same id the default one and the one i want to add . So can i use the rpc instead of the id with wallet_switchEthereumChain ?
